# Why does a String DataTemplate cause a stack overflow exception?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a couple of DataTemplates defined in the resources of a ContentControl:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
  <Label Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dmodels:CBClient}"> <!-- Client Details Template -->
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Client Details" Background="{StaticResource brush_Client}" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Id:" Background="{StaticResource brush_Client}" Foreground="White" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=ClientId}" Background="{StaticResource brush_Client}" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,1,0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource EditButton}" />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

- If I return a CBClient object, I get the proper display from the defined DataTemplate.
- If I return a string, I get a StackOverflowException.
- If I eliminate the String DataTemplate and return a string, I get the string displayed, but not formatted as I want it.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to wrap the basic string return into a full class, and expose a message property? Is there no way to combine complex objects with integral types for DataTemplates?

Thanks.

J

Comment: Unlike told in the answer, no TextBlock is "automatically generated" by the Label. Your problem is that Label is a ContentControl, which may automatically choose a ContentTemplate. When your data type is string, the Label chooses your DataTemplate, which in turn contains another Label, which again chooses your DataTemplate, ad infinitum.

Comment: Thanks, @Clemens. That makes sense as to the error, I think. Is it because the Label is defined within the scope of the ContentControl's resources, that it, too, was looking through the same set of available DataTemplates? I hadn't defined any DataTemplates for the Label, itself. And, obviously, other Labels, outside that scope (control), were not affected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You introduced a complication by using a Label. It automatically generates a textblock if you bind to a string. Binding in that way has an odd effect if you rely on it automatically adding the textblock. I should think it's because it sees an object rather than a string from the type of the property you're binding.
You could just do:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </Label>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: If you don't use the Label in relation to another control, then just use the TextBlock and align center with TextAlignment="Center"

Comment: Indeed. I wanted to stress how a label would still work if you explicitly gave it a textblock as content though.